# python ~ youtube-dl: error: no such option: --audio-format

Tags: python, audio, youtube-dl

Here is my code :

```
call(['youtube-dl', '-i', '--extract-audio', '--audio-format mp3','-w','ytsearch:'+song ,'-o '+song2file(song)+'.%(ext)s'], shell=False)
```

Note:This is an implementation of this code : `youtuble-dl -i --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -w ytsearch:Wham Bam -o WhamBam.%(ext)s`
Where song =  Wham Bam, When I run this cmd it works  perfectly but the python implementation is not working.

On running it, it returns me this error:

> youtube-dl: error: no such option: --audio-format

Comment: `youtuble-dl -i --extract-audio --audio-format mp3`: "When I run this cmd it works perfectly". This just can't be: 1) youtuble-dl: typo and 2) you just found out that it is `--audio-format=mp3`, so please formulate your questions better...

Comment: `--audio-format mp3` is correct, but it must be two arguments. The original error message likely reads. `youtube-dl: error: no such option: --audio-format mp3`. (Source: I wrote much of the code).

Answer (score 0):

as part of solution, it better to format your string properly like this:

```
arg= ['-i', '--extract-audio', '--audio-format mp3','-w','ytsearch:'+song ,'-o 
'+song2file(song)+'.%(ext)s'];
yt-arg= " ".join(str(x) for x in arg);
```

then call it

```
subprocess.call(['youtube-dl', yt-arg], shell=False)
```

this already solve the problem you describe but it seems still have issue on the -o option.
please remember to format your string properly, not carelessly.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the issue is coming from the fact that you're lumping arguments together in a list entry when they should be separate entries in the list for subprocess to handle them correctly.

In this example it would be something like this:

```
args= [
    '-i',
    '--extract-audio',
    '--audio-format',
    'mp3',
]
subprocess.call(args)
```

Notice that `--audio-format` and `mp3` are separated