# Python ~ffmpeg 5_second_video.mp3: No such file or directory Conversion failed

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Here is my python code :

```
    call(['ffmpeg', '-loop', '1',  '-y', '-i', '5_second_video.jpg', '-i','5_second_video.mp3' , '-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-shortest', song +'.mp4'], shell=False)
```

There is a file called 5_second_video.mp3 in my desktop but it is returning me this error

> 5_second_video.mp3: No such file or directory
>   Conversion failed!

Comment: yes, but your current directory is probably not your desktop.

Comment: The working directory must not be your desktop then. It's probably the folder that contains your script.

Comment: can you at least review the answers to your questions before posting others? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142528/python-youtube-dl-error-no-such-option-audio-format. 3 questions on youtube/subprocess stuff in the week-end, that sounds a lot to me.

Comment: Not only are you probably not in the directory where the video is your video is almost certainly called `5_second_video.mpeg` or `.mp4` not `.jpg`

Comment: You should add `-movflags +faststart` if this is going to be played by viewers via progressive download.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing `'-o '+song2file(song)+'.%(ext)s'` to `'-o'+song2file(song)+'.%(ext)s'`. The space was the problem.